# Wasn't it actually Snape disguised as Lupin who met Harry, Hermione, and Ron in 12 Grimmauld Place?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape, grimmauld-place, remus-lupin

I have the feeling that it was Snape, disguised as Lupin, who showed up in 12 Grimmauld Place in the chapter *The Bribe* in the last Harry Potter book. Supporting evidence for the claim:

- Snape already knows the information Lupin gives Harry to recognize him. It is also so-Snape-ish to quickly blame Hermione and Ron for lowering their defense too soon.
- Lupin had already given up directly helping them on Dumbledore's mission. It is also not in Lupin's character to leave the wife and the baby during this time given we know him in the books as a less adventurous person compared to James and Black. After all, what was Lupin's business to endanger himself and show up there?
- When Harry meets Lupin at Bill's place, he acts as if it had never happened.
- We know Snape could bypass the protection set by Mad-Eye. The Chapter *The Prince's Tale* reveals he could actually be there.
- Snape had shown the desire in his memories to know about Harry's mission set by Dumbledore. Maybe he thinks he can help and that's why he is insisting to join them.

Comment: I can't understand why this post gets downvotes. It is a good question actually.

Comment: Plot twist. Ron Weasley was actually Snape under Polyjuice the whole time.

Comment: If Snape joined Harry & friends on their travels, does he think no one at Hogwarts would notice he were never there? Or is it like in "Mrs. Doubtfire" where he's going back and forth and reapplying the disguise every time?

Answer (score 22):

**Almost certainly not.** Lupin informs Harry and company that Tonks is pregnant. How could Snape possibly know that? He also speaks about the matter with genuine torment about what he may have inflicted upon his child.

More to the point, I don't see why such a major twist would never be revealed in the book, giving it zero pay-off. Maybe Ron in Chapter Seven of *Goblet of Fire* is actually Padma Patil using Polyjuice Potion. But if JK never said that was the case, I don't see any reason why we should think so.

Comment: I agree. But one possible theory as of why Snape can know Tonks' pregnancy, maybe Phineas Nigellus knows, or perhaps Mundungus. Mundungus was part of the plan when Snape ordered him to say to the Order of the Phoenix his own plan of using polyjuice potion and brooms to escape Harry from his house.

Comment: Don;t be so silly, @TenthJustice. Ron as Padma Patil? Ridiculous. He's *clearly* a time-travelling Dumbledore.

Answer (score 16):

**It was Lupin**, because during a episode of Potterwatch Lupin praises Harry for his decision making.

**Firstly Romulus is actually Lupin**

> “Excellently put, Royal, and you’ve got my vote for Minister of Magic if we ever get out of this mess,” said Lee. “And now, over to Romulus for our popular feature ’Pals of Potter.”’
>
> “Thanks, River,” said another very familiar voice. Ron started to speak, but
>   Hermione forestalled him in a whisper.
>
> “We know it’s Lupin!”
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 22, The Deathly Hallows**</sup></sub>

Lupin admits Harry made the right decision

> “And what would you say to Harry if you knew he was listening, Romulus?”
>
> “I’d tell him we’re all with him in spirit,” said Lupin, **then hesitated slightly, “And I’d tell him to follow his instincts, which are good and nearly always right.”**
>
> Harry looked at Hermione, whose eyes were full of tears.
>
> “Nearly always right,” she repeated.
>
> “Oh, didn’t I tell you?” said Ron in surprise. “**Bill told me Lupin’s living
>   with Tonks again!** And apparently she’s getting pretty big too. . . ”
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 22, The Deathly Hallows**</sup></sub>

The sentence "**Bill told me Lupin’s living with Tonks again!**", indicates that Lupin had stayed away from Tonks for her safety and Harry's words convinced him to go back to Tonks.

Comment: If there is a possibility that the visitor to Grimmauld Place could have been Snape polyjuiced, why couldn't Romulus also have been Snape polyjuiced?

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think so.

Your theories have so much possibilities, but Rowling would definitely detail in the book 7 each and every help Snape has given, including his suggestions and priorities making Harry safe.

Similar to the first answer, Tonks is pregnant, which is a very personal thing for Lupib to say.. My theory: Maybe Snape knows it by someone who can inform him, and my best guess would be Mundungus since he ordered him to suggest to the OOTP to use polyjuice potion to make replicas of Harry. But, I can't say it is Snape who was disguised as Lupin since it's not very canonical to say, and one more thing to remember, why would Snape tell Harry Tonks is pregnant 'yehey let us celebrate', Snape doesn't even care for Lupin and it would be odd and pretty weird for the Order to know there's an impersonator. Snape will definitely not risk this movement since the Order will be in s total panic when they knew a traitor entered Grimmauld Place. Besides, Lupin went to the Shell Cottage, again, to inform Harry about his honor. If it was Snape who was in Sirius' place, then Lupin will also inform Harry that Tonks is pregnant, since he wouldn't think that someone has already informed him.

Second, Rowling wanted to make every good deeds of Snape very clear. Snape played a big part in hiding the sword and keeping it from Bellatrix. He played a big part when he protected Lily's son and defend Harry from Dumbledore the time he knew Harry was kept alive so he can die at the proper moment. Remember that it was included in his memory that he was the one who suggested to the Order to use polyjuice potion.

I'm confidently sure that would be included in book 7 if it was really Snape, but I don't think Snape will waste time following Harry disguised as Lupin to inform what happens at the Ministry, what if someone followed him? That could end his fake loyalty to the Dark Lord.

Answer (score 0):

I would not say so. It would not be Snape-ish for Lupin to reprimand Ron and Hermione for putting down their defenses so easily. It was a dark time, and they needed someone whom they could trust, probably close to Harry's father. Lupin also knew that as their former Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher, he should at least be telling them to watch their own safety!

Lupin here was a worried father, he was in a dilemma. He did not want to endanger his own child's life with Voldemort's wrath, but also wanted to help his best friend's son, who he viewed as a family. Under great pressure, Lupin was undergoing a struggle with himself.

We also know that whatever Snape wanted to do, he wanted to take revenge on Voldemort and kill him. I seriously doubt that Snape would go against Dumbledore's orders. We know that in a few days Snape will be the headmaster of Hogwarts and he will have a picture of Dumbledore hanging behind his study. In his effort to kill the Dark Lord, I believe Snape would not dare go against Dumbledore's plan.

Meanwhile Remus under such tremendous pressure might agree to do something rash. He was a werewolf and most of his kind were joining the Dark Lord's side. Two of his best friends had died along with their families. Even though he loved Harry, he didn't want his family to die and thought Tonks might be safer off with her parents while he fought against Voldemort.